# Given a PRF $F$ , is $G(s) = F_s(1)\|F_s(2)\|\cdots \|F_s(n+1)$ a PRG?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-generator, distinguisher

If $F$ a PRF, and we construct $G$ using $F$ in the following way: 
$$G(s) = F_s(1)\|F_s(2)\|\cdots \|F_s(n+1)$$
where $|s|= n$.

Is $G$ then a PRG? If so how can I prove this? If not how can $G(s)$ be distinguished from a random $r$? And what if $n+1 <$ range of $F_s$? or it could be for any $n > |s|$.

Comment: Well, this question effectively is: "Is CTR a PRG"?

Comment: What have you tried? There are very many basic results which are proved in similar ways.

Comment: @fkraiem i tried to make a reduction , given adversary A(distinguisher for G) , building a distinguisher D that emulate A on F_s , and return 1 if and only if A return 1

Comment: Well, that's the right way. But what is the problem there? Because this works without doing a single calculation on your part. You just need to relay queries the right way. And you have the same probability of success as $A$.

Comment: related https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64209/building-a-cpa-secure-sctr-from-a-prf

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following game:

[image]

I assume certain familiarity with the definitions of Katz and Lindell book (this is exercise 3.14 in the book). In particular, $O$ is denoting an oracle. It can be either a random function oracle (if $b = 0$) or the output of a random function $F_s$ (if $b = 1$). What you do essentially in your distinguisher is query this oracle $l(n)$ times. This is a generalization with respect to your setting. Instead of $n$ one can write an arbitrary polynomial $l(n)$ since the involved algorithms are PPT.

In any case, note that when you gather all the $b_i$ you get $y = G(s)$ or $y$ uniformly distributed in $n \cdot l(n)$. This is because the independent concatenation of uniformly distributed bits is uniformly distributed (?). So, indeed what you have in the last part is a distinguisher for the PRG game.

If you assume that $G$ is not a PRG then we can use an attack $A$ that has non-negligible probability $|P[WIN_{PRG}] - \frac 1 2|$. Then, we realize that one wins in the game PRF if and only if one wins in the PRG game (case distinction on $b$). Therefore, $|P[WIN_{PRF}] - \frac 1 2| = |P[WIN_{PRG}] - \frac 1 2|$ is non-negligible, but this contradicts the definition of PRF.